# Close dialog causes Too Much Recursion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a table with rows which can be deleted by clicking on an icon next to each row. When the icon is clicked a confirmation dialog appears asking the user to confirm.

Whichever action is taken (Yes, No, X) causes a Too Much Recursion error. The function works, in that the row is deleted, and the dialog closes, but it causes the TMR error and eats up Firefox memory.

```
$('a img.delete').live('click', function(event){
rowid = this.name;$('#' + rowid).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
$("#dialog-del-r").dialog('open');
return false;
});
```

```
 $("#dialog-del-r").dialog({autoOpen:false,height:225,width:250,modal:false,position:[700,150],
buttons: {'Yes': function() {
   $('#summary-report').empty();
   $('#' + rowid).remove();
   $(this).dialog('close');
  },
  'No': function() {
   $('#' + rowid).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
   $(this).dialog('close');
  }}
  ,close: function() {
   $('#' + rowid).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
   $(this).dialog('close');
  }
 });
```

Any of these lines $(this).dialog('close'); cause the problem to happen.

I also have a form reset button which does exactly the same thing:

```
 $('#reset-form').button({icons: {primary:'ui-icon-trash'}}).click(function(){
$('#dialog-reset').dialog('open');
});
```

```
 $("#dialog-reset").dialog({autoOpen:false,height:225,width:250,modal:false,position:[200,350],buttons: {'Yes': function() {$(this).dialog('close');location.reload(true);},'No': function() {$(this).dialog('close');}},close: function() {$(this).dialog('close');}});
```

Comment: Is it possible that rowid automatically readjust.

Comment: rowid is based on the row in the table (which can grow or shrink) but that is a red herring.


Look at the dialog-reset code. That does not have any rowid var and that code too generates the TMR error.


The problem seems to be with the closing of the dialog.


1. Reset form icon is pressed.

2. dialog-reset.dialog is opened

3. User asked to confirm if they want the form reset


Whatever choice the user takes (Yes, No, X) the TMR error is generated.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to work this one out. The close, section closes the dialog automatically whereas I had the dialog('close') in there.

```
  ,close: function() {
   $('#' + rowid).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
   $(this).dialog('close');
  }
```

should be:

```
  ,close: function() {
   $('#' + rowid).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
  }
```

Comment: This saved my life, thanks a ton! Definitely a non-obvious error.